# Kafka consumer not returning any events

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

The below Scala kafka consumer is not returning any events from the `poll` call.

However, the topic is correct, and I can see events being sent to the topic  using the console consumer:

```
/opt/kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --topic my_topic --from-beginning
```

I also see the topic in my Scala code sample below when I step through it with a debugger and invoke `kafkaConsumer.listTopics()`

Also, this is called from a single unit test, so I'm only creating one instance of this trait and consumer (i.e. another consumer instance can't be consuming the messages). I'm also using a random group_id.

Is there anything wrong with the below code/configuration?

```
import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.{ByteArrayDeserializer, StringDeserializer}

import scala.util.Random

trait KafkaTest {

  val kafkaConsumerProperties = new Properties()

  kafkaConsumerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")

  kafkaConsumerProperties.put("group.id", Random.alphanumeric.take(10).mkString)

  kafkaConsumerProperties.put("key.deserializer", classOf[ByteArrayDeserializer])

  kafkaConsumerProperties.put("value.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer])

  val kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](kafkaConsumerProperties)

kafkaConsumer.subscribe(java.util.Collections.singletonList("my_topic"))

  def checkKafkaHasReceivedEvent(): Assertion = {

    val kafkaEvents = kafkaConsumer.poll(2000) // Always returns 0 events?
    ...
  }
}
```

Increasing the poll timeout doesn't help either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To read from beginning AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG property has to be set to earliest, by default it "latest"

```
kafkaConsumerProperties.put(
    ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, 
    OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST.toString().toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm seeing events returned now - however would there by any reason why my code above is returning less events (298) than the console consumer (400+)? The code above isn't returning the new event my test inserts (i'm seeing it on the console consumer though). Maybe my Scala code is only getting events from one partition? Is there any way to get events from all partitions?

Comment: I had to add this line just before the poll call, things seem to work now:

kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(kafkaConsumer.assignment())