# Incorrect Kafka offset across consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a topic which is consumed by two consumer groups. There are 10 messages in the topic.

Application 1 (Consumer group  1)has finished processing of messages from topic and when i describe kafka-consumer-groups (with --group consumerGroup1) then it correctly shows CURRENT-OFFSET =10 and LOG-END-OFFSET =10.

Now i start application 2 (Consumer group 2) which is consuming same topic. It is not processing messages . When i describe kafka-consumer-groups (with --group consumerGroup2) , it surprisingly shows CURRENT-OFFSET =10 and LOG-END-OFFSET =10.

Ideally  this should not happen and kafka should be able to recognize that for the consumer group 2 there are no message processed and it should process all messages.

What could be wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka consumer not returning any events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867775/kafka-consumer-not-returning-any-events)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `earliest` property in your KafkaStreams `Properties`

[Kafka consumer not returning any events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867775/kafka-consumer-not-returning-any-events/53869137#53869137)

Comment: All heroes don't wear capes . It Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot