# Kafka Consumer Issue (Receive with latest offset)

Tags: apache-kafka

When my producer and consumer is listening at the same time,i can see the message. When my consumer is down and sending messages from producer,I can't see it from the consumer when i turn up. But when i give from beginning setting,I can see the message. 
Please assist.

Comment: Be default it reads from latest: you can read: `auto.offset.reset` https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

Comment: By default,I didn't consume it. Do i need to set this explicitly? If so where i have to set.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and [ask] in the [help]. Also, this seems off topic and unclear.

Comment: @satheeshS, Yes you have, it depends on, what type of clients you are using, ex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867775/kafka-consumer-not-returning-any-events/53869137#53869137

Answer (score 1):

> I can't see it from the consumer when i turn up

If you start the same consumer of the same `group.id`, it will reset from the previously stored partitions, assuming your consumer offsets have been committed previously.
The default behavior for new consumer groups is to start at the latest offset, though, and you need to set `auto.offset.reset=earliest` to start from the beginning. In addition, the offsets are automatically committed by default and it is recommended to disable this in order to guarantee every message is actually processed at least once, and do manual offset commits. There is lots of good documentation on this in the [KafkaConsumer JavaDoc](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html).

If you are using the `console-consumer`, then it always defaults to the latest offset until adding `--from-beginning` but you can also add `--group <name>` to join/resume a consumer group.