# Cannot produce Kafka message on topic exists on AWS instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to push a message to a Kafka Topic. The topic is created on AWS EC2 instance. When I push message to the topic from my machine (localhost) nothing happened. However when I tried to push it manually from the EC2 instance it worked normally. Also I make sure that my instance allows all in/out bound traffic.

**server.properties file**

```
    zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=1000000
# public IP for the instance
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://18.222.151.131:9092 
# private IP for the instance
listeners=PLAINTEXT://172.31.43.18:9092
```

**And below is my producer java code**

```
public static void run() throws InterruptedException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "18.222.151.131:9092");
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer(properties);
        kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic, "Hello AWS"));
        producer.close();
        }
```

Comment: What are the results of using `kafka-console-producer.sh` script?

Comment: the messages are pushed successfully to the topic when I used kafka-console-producer.sh.

Comment: Try to add `get() ` call to `kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic, "Hello AWS"));`

Comment: @wardziniak, tried this. Nothing pushed and I got exception "Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms"

Comment: @wardziniak, after allowing in/out bound traffic to my instance the "Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms" disappears, but I still cannot find my pushed message.

Comment: What command do you use to read it? Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867775/kafka-consumer-not-returning-any-events/53869137#53869137

Comment: @wardziniak, I'm checking the consumed messages using this command from EC2 instance terminal **bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 18.222.151.131:2181 --topic TwitterStream --from-beginning**

Comment: Try to use following command: `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 18.222.151.131:9092 --topic TwitterStream --from-beginning`

Comment: @wardziniak, results `bootstrap-server' is not a recognized option`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187364/discussion-between-wardziniak-and-islam).